# Excel vba nested inner subs like in python, java

Tags: vba, excel

In other programming languages there is a way to put some code into a separate function that gets called from the first one, for instance, in java:

```
public void exercise()  {
       run();
       jump();
       walk();
}
```

Is there a way in vba to put subs into one another? I tried to

```
Sub test1()  
    test2()
End Sub

Sub test2()
    MsgBox("test2")
End Sub
```

But it gives mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this without parentheses:

```
Sub test1()  
    test2
End Sub
```

Parentheses are needed to enclose arguments in order to assign the output of a function to a variable. If your sub took arguments, you would do like:

```
Sub test1()  
    test2 "Hello", "World"
End Sub

Sub test2(arg1, arg2) 
    Msgbox arg1 & " - " & arg2
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're passing arguments to a function rather than a procedure you need to include parentheses, if the function doesn't take arguments then you don't.  So if `Function test2` just returned the string of the result of `arg1 & " - " & arg2` you'd need `MsgBox test2("Hello", "World")`, if the function returned "Hello - World"` without any arguments you could use `MsgBox test2`.  Simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `call` to call the subroutine:

```
call test2()
```

Comment: You are not required to use the Call keyword when calling a procedure. However, if you use the Call keyword to call a procedure that requires arguments, argumentlist must be enclosed in parentheses. If you omit the Call keyword, you also must omit the parentheses around argumentlist. If you use either Call syntax to call any intrinsic or user-defined function, the function's return value is discarded. To pass a whole array to a procedure, use the array name followed by empty parentheses.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/call-statement

Comment: Ah, I forgot about leaving out the paranthesis, @DarrenBartrup-Cook you are right, of course. VBA is a rare beast in my work now. :-)